# Is there a way to get just a list of filenames of a remote mercurial repo?

Tags: mercurial, file-listing

Question is basically in the title. Is there any way to just have a list of files and directories in a remote repo fetched/displayed? I am asking, because I have a large repo and I just need a to glance (programmatically) at a list of directory names - not the whole repo (which is about 1G).

Comment: Do you want to access the list programmatically? If not you can just browse the web interface, no?

Comment: Yes, programmatically - otherwise web interfaces are just fine.

Comment: You could run a command over ssh. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

`hg locate` lists the content of a repository, filters can be applied on demand.

Comment: Yes, this works locally - but I'm talking about listing only the files of a remote repository.

Comment: @miku: `hg -R repopath locate`